# 'Apps' for Ask Ubuntu

Tags: discussion, add-on

AskUbuntu.com has a powerful API that allows developers to create rich applications to check questions, comments and user data from the site. Those apps can be browser extensions, desktop widgets or standalone applications.

If you know about an application related to Ask Ubuntu, then please share it.

> Note: I have moved my AskUbuntu Add-on
>   to a new answer